# Displaying part of a random webpage from a website

Tags: java, html, web

To preface, I am a beginner java learner trying to figure out what I need to learn / master before I can tackle this problem. So I am looking for broad stroke / process needed to achieve this.

I am trying to make a program that displays a random page from a medical image atlas website, while hiding most elements from the page but the picture. Then with a click of a button, the comments/description is revealed. This program would be great for studying/reviewing spot diagnosis or teaching.

The website url format is /image.asp?n=X&Case=Y
where X = picture # from specific disease entity and Y = Disease entity. The X can be up to 50, and Y up to 750 (broadly grouped by organ system)

Ideally the program would generate a link with random X and random Y within that range, test to see if the webpage exist. If not, repeat; if it does then it gets fed into the program that hides certain elements from the webpage. Clicking a button would reveal the element that contains comment/description of the image.

What's the best way to accomplish this using java? What do I need to learn to attempt this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms, you would want to use 2 pages:

Page one is visible and is what you show people

page 2 is hidden and you want to use the curl function of PHP to load a website, then you parse it for the information you need using substr, and other easily googled techniques that go with it (look up parsing or substr).

Then you print that as an xml format and load it using JavaScript via your first page.

It is theoretically possible to call via json, directly but you will likely run into CORS issues.

The tricky part is loading the xml, so let me help you out with that:

```
function loaddata(lurl){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET",lurl,false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
    x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    for (i=0;i<x.childNodes.length;i++){
        if (x.childNodes.item(i).nodeType==1){
        firstNode=x.childNodes.item(i).childNodes;
        Arrtype = firstNode[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        if (typeof window[Arrtype] == 'undefined'){
            window[Arrtype] = new Array();
        }
        Arrsize = window[Arrtype].length;
        window[Arrtype][Arrsize] = new Array();
        Arrc = 0;
            for (j=0;j<firstNode.length;j++){
                if (firstNode[j].nodeType==1 && j != 1){
                    if(isNaN(firstNode[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == false){
                        window[Arrtype][Arrsize][Arrc] = parseFloat(firstNode[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue,10);
                    }
                    else{
                        window[Arrtype][Arrsize][Arrc] = firstNode[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                Arrc = Arrc + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can find an example of a working xml file for that script done in php here:

http://www.tffan.com/tiles/pml.php

Also, here is part of a curl script: it does require a url to have been posted, but you should get the idea by studying it:

```
$projUrl = $_POST["opt_url"];
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $projUrl);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
if (empty($buffer)){
    print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
}
else{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($buffer);
    $tag = 'a';
    $elem = 'href';
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tag);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $hotra = $tag->getAttribute($elem);
        if (substr($hotra, 0, 3) == "htt") {
            if (substr($hotra, 0, 13) == "http://ssh.tf") {
                if (strpos($hotra, 'Thread', 0) == 0 ){
                    array_push($a,$tag->getAttribute($elem));
                }
            }
        }
    }
$doc = null;
echo $buffer;
}
```

I hope that helps.